# Loading the TexturesAtlas in a seperate Thread

Tags: java, android, libgdx

The tween animations is getting disturbed when I load the TextureAtlas. I wish to load my texture Atlas in a seperate thread.Could you please guide me to the safe usage of a thread in Libgdx. Any example / sample code is highly appreciated.

Comment: TextureAtlases cannot be loaded in a separate thread because the texture must be loaded into GL memory. If you try it, they will look corrupted. Using AssetManager can help break up the loading over a few frames if your atlas contains multiple pages, but there will probably still be a noticeable stutter.

Comment: I am not English speaker, but I think they are different questions, one is on a different thread load and another is on the state of charge of the asset. it may or may not use a different thread, be as efficient or not, I do not understand the downvote

Comment: Thanks Angel for your understanding !

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and best way to do this is to use the LibGdx AssetLoader class.

See https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets

From the page...

> Loading a specific asset is simple:
>
> ```
> manager.load("data/mytexture.png", Texture.class);
> manager.load("data/myfont.fnt", BitmapFont.class);
> manager.load("data/mymusic.ogg", Music.class);
> ```
>
> These calls will enqueue those assets for loading. The assets will be
>   loaded in the order we called the AssetManager#load() method. Some
>   loaders allow you to also pass parameters to them via
>   AssetManager#load(). Say we want to specify a non-default filter and
>   mipmapping setting for loading a texture:
>
> ```
> TextureParameter param = new TextureParameter(); param.minFilter =
> TextureFilter.Linear; param.genMipMaps = true;
> manager.load("data/mytexture.png", Texture.class, param);
> ```
>
> Look into the loaders mentioned above to find out about their
>   parameters.
>
> So far we only queued assets to be loaded. The AssetManager does not
>   yet load anything. To kick this off we have to call
>   AssetManager#update() continuously, say in our
>   ApplicationListener#render() method:
>
> ```
> public MyAppListener implements ApplicationListener {    
>
>    public void render() {
>       if(manager.update()) {
>          // we are done loading, let's move to another screen!
>       }
>
>       // display loading information
>       float progress = manager.getProgress()
>       ... left to the reader ...
>     } 
> }
> ```
>
> As long as AssetManager#update() returns false you know it's still
>   loading assets. To poll the concrete state of loading you can use
>   AssetManager#getProgress(), which returns a number between 0 and 1
>   indicating the percentage of assets loaded so far. There are other
>   methods in AssetManager that give you similar information, like
>   AssetManager#getLoadedAssets() or AssetManager#getQueuedAssets(). You
>   have to call AssetManager#update() to keep loading!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Dropout - Good idea, thanks... I've edited to include a section from the page.

Comment: The community thanks you! :)

Comment: With this setup, I get a black screen while loading. How to avoid it

Comment: It could be due to any number of reasons. Probably best to start a new question with relevant code etc.